# Cooling system pipes flow or pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Why in cooling systems such as chilled water network and $\mathrm{AHU}$, the pipes network is indicted by pressure gauge instead of measure of flow

As the heat transfer equation $mC_{p}T$ 
The heat transfer is related to mass flow rate not pressure to make sure the process is working efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Here is why.

Mass flow meters are expensive. Pressure gauges are very cheap. When the pumps in the system are running, the system is under pressure. When they are running at the correct speed, to support the as-designed mass flow rate, the pressure takes a well-defined value. When they are running at the wrong speed, the pressure reading will be wrong. Therefore, to tell if the flow rate is correct, all you have to do is look at the pressure gauge.

Answer (score 0):

Both pressure and mass flow rate are important in convective heat transfer. The pressure of the fluid (in this case chilled water) influences the convective coefficient. The mass flow rate can be considered as the rate of renewal of fluid. The higher the rate of renewal the more isothermal the process becomes and the greater the heat transfer becomes due to maintaining the temperature differential (isothermal).